# AWS Redis Cluster - MOVE error

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, redis-cluster

I try to execute a hmset command on AWS Redis Cluster, and I'm getting the following "moved" error. Not sure what is going on.

***MOVED 7652 10.0.4.210:6379***

```
from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster

startup_nodes = [{"host": self.host, "port": self.port}]
client = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes,
                                        decode_responses=True,
                                        skip_full_coverage_check=True)

client.hmset('my_key', {'abc':'123'})
```

Comment: what's the value of self.port? is it 7652?

Comment: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#playing-with-the-cluster

Comment: In my case, I use a GUI client and I didn't start the connection with `Cluster`.

Answer (score 34):

As your data is sharded and distributed into different nodes in the cluster, you should use `-c` option to be able to connect to redis in cluster mode.

In your question, it is not known what type of client library you using, however the same concept, you need to use a library that supports `cluster mode`. Here is a [list of client packages in nodejs](https://redis.io/clients#nodejs)

If you're trying to get data it will redirect you as a client to the correct  shard/partition that holds the requested data.

if you have `redis-cli`, you can try this:

```
redis-cli -c -h {REDIS_HOST_OR_PORT} -p 6379
```

if you have `docker` installed, you can connect to the cluster using the following:

```
docker run -ti --rm redis redis-cli -c -h {REDIS_HOST_OR_IP} -p 6379
```

Comment: thank you. actually, the -c switch is the answer which switches to the cluster-mode.

Answer (score 1):

The "MOVED" error happens when you connect to one node in a redis cluster with standalone mode, and data you query is on other nodes in the cluster.

I don't know how your `StrictRedisCluster` implenmented, but something is definitively wrong in this client.

Answer (score 0):

For get commands you may want to run:

```
READONLY
```

first as one of the following [might have happened](https://redis.io/commands/readonly/):

> 1. The client sent a command about hash slots never served by the
>    master of this replica.
> 2. The cluster was reconfigured (for example resharded) and the replica
>    is no longer able to serve commands for a given hash slot.